# Axios call to Springboot backend responding is not forwarding to new page after returning response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

My postmapping "login" in my controller is returning a 200. But I'm getting undefined and I believe it is from my axios call. I know that the undefined error is being reported from the catch block in the console

Axios call -

```
  submit() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("email", this.email)
    formData.set("password", this.password)
    formData.set("staySignedIn", this.staySignedIn)

    // When the client/server sides are running from the same port (AWS) the url for this api call should be changed to /api/v1/login
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/login", formData,
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
        .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res); // test
          if (res.data.code === 200) {
            this.router.push('/dashboard')
            console.log("success");
          } else {
            console.log(res.data.code);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
  }
```

[Response from dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2QkM.png)

[Response from test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gscd.png)

Comment: Which line is logging the undefined?

Comment: @aksappy console.log(err) and the else from what I can tell

Comment: can you add an error here, if it is possible please console log the status code at the begging of the then block?

Comment: Add this line before your if condition - `console.log(res)` - and show us what you get please

Comment: @aksappy Done under "response from test". It's responding with my email and the correct (encrypted) password string

Comment: Well, please edit this question and show us what you have got from the console.log statements. You can mask the credentials, we are interested to see what you are seeing

Comment: @aksappy I edited the question and test picture. Is the "undefined" a non-issue then, if I'm receiving credentials back?

Comment: Yea it is a non-issue. You can lookup the response values and then construct the javascript code accordingly. You might not want the credentials back in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios response schema documentation is [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)

Unless you have a key `code` in your controller response, `response.data.code` will be undefined.

Try `res.status` instead if you want to check the HTTP status.

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/login", formData,
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
        .then(function (res) {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            this.router.push('/dashboard')
            console.log("success");
          } else {
            console.log(res.status);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
```

**EDIT**
You seem to be sending back the password back in the response. Even though the password is encrypted, better restrict exposing it in the response.